# ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, ant, slf4j

I'm trying to deploy a web app to tomcat using ANT but I ran into this error (the app compiles fine in a simple ant task. The issue occurs when Tomcat is restarted):

### Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 24 more
```

I red a couple of answers around here which state that besides `slf4j` an implementation such as `log4j`. This is an excerpt of the `build.xml` file:

```
<pathelement location="${slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar}"/>
<pathelement location="${log4j.jar}"/>
```

These are path elements used in the classpath of the build's `javac` command.

Besides not adding log4j as a dependency, what may be other reasons for this issue.
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is your web app using spring and hibernate in it. then you will have to include slf4j as a dependency

Comment: @vikeng21 slf4j is added as a dependency :)

Comment: Do you really have properties named `slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar` and `log4j.jar` that you need to use the ${...} syntax/format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the .jar files your app need to
$TOMCAT/webapps/$YOUR_WEB_APP/WEB-INF/lib/

and then restart tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem copying this 2 JARs below.

**from** (assuming you are using *Maven* to manage your dependecies):

- *.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4f-api/N.N.NN/slf4j-api-N.N.NN.jar*
- *.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4f-log4j12/N.N.NN/slf4j-log4j12-N.N.NN.jar*

**to** (apache installation folder):

- *apache-tomcat-M.M.MM/lib*